# How to get the multiple key value pairs from jsonb object in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have column response_payload in table response as below

```json
{"studentName":"Karate","studentStream":"API Testing", "studentAge":18}
```

Now I need to get the new json object based on my keys. For example, if my keys are studentName and studentStream I must get

```json
{"studentName":"Karate","studentStream":"API Testing"}
```

In case if I provide invalid key, it should not bring anything related to invalid key.

I have tried json_build_object built-in function in postgresql, it is bringing invalid key and value as below

```
select json_build_object('invalidKey', payload -> 'invalidValue') 
from response
```

O/P:- `{"invalidKey":"null"}`

I want output when invalid key and value is provided, it should not bring anything as below

O/p:- `{}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jsonb_strip_nulls`

```
select 
  jsonb_strip_nulls(jsonb_build_object('invalidKey', payload -> 'invalidValue')) 
from response
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I have some other payloads for other student IDs where some key's values are null like {"studentName":"Karate","studentStream":"API Testing", "studentAge":18, "fatherName":null}. In that case, above query will not fetch even if it is a valid key.